# SQL update boolean value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building an application in Code Igniter. I am having an issue updating a boolean cell in my database. Here is my statement:

```
public function updateHide($id) {
        $sql = "UPDATE holiday_request SET hide = '1' WHERE holiday_request_id = " . (int)$id;
        $this->db->query($sql);
        echo $this->db->affected_rows();            
    }
```

I am using the affected rows function to quickly check in Firebug that it has affected the valid row.
I have printed out the SQL statement and tested it in PHP Myadmin and it works fine, meaning the ID is correct and there is a valid row in the database. 
I can't for the life of me figure out why the table is not updating. Could anyobdy point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you try not quoting the `1`? Also are you sure `$id` is the value you think it is?

Comment: you are sure the function is running? perhaps echo something when the function is run?  I assume there is no shown response from `echo $this->db->affected_rows();` ?

Comment: It would be very useful for you to check if the query function returns a success and if not to echo out the error.

Comment: I would recommend you to escape the parameter to avoid SQL injection. Use `PDO::quote($id)` or something similar.

Comment: Did you try with Active Record syntax http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I did use the Active Syntax Error syntax and it throws up a 'database error'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help guys but it turns out I was being an idiot and passing an array to the function without realising.

Answer (score -1):

For updates I think you should use the `exec` method instead:

```
$affected_rows = $this->db->exec($sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to load database into your function as below

```
public function updateHide($id) {
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = "UPDATE holiday_request SET hide = '1' WHERE holiday_request_id = " . (int)$id;
  $this->db->query($sql);
  echo $this->db->affected_rows();            
}
```

Got hint from [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Updating-Data-P290.html)

Answer (score -3):

Set the value to TRUE not to '1'

```
public function updateHide($id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE holiday_request SET hide = TRUE WHERE holiday_request_id = " . (int)$id;
    $this->db->query($sql);
    echo $this->db->affected_rows();            
}
```

Comment: pointless. true is 1 in mysql anyways. and `'1'` casts to 1 and true as well.

Comment: bool and boolean are synonymous with tinyint which is 0 or 1 so this is not really the case